# onLoadedMetadata <video> doesn't work in next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, jsx

Hello I have this little component over here.

```
{srcs.map((src, index) =>
                <video
                    key={"mediaPlayer" + index}
                    src={src}
                    onLoadedMetadata={(e) => console.log(e.currentTarget.duration)}
                />
            )}
```

I want to have access to e.currentTarget.duration as soon as it is available to me and log it into the console but for whatever reason `onLoadedMetadata` doesn't run the function does anyone have any clue why? My assumption is that this is because of server side rendering preformed by next.js but I'm really not sure.